# B::Lint complaining about the use of $_

Tags: perl, lint, static-code-analysis

I'm using B::Lint for static code analysis of the Perl code, and I'm confused about why it is complaining about certain lines of my script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @numbers;

open(my $fh, "<", "phonenumbers.txt");
while(<$fh>) {
    my @num = $_ =~ /(\d+)/g;
    push @numbers, join('',@num);
}
foreach(@numbers) {
    print("$_\n");
}
```

Besides `push @numbers, join('',@num);` every line below `open(my $fh, "<", "phonenumbers.txt");` is underlined by the B::Lint, most of them with the following description: "*Use of $_*", which seems somewhat reasonable for me since this practice could make the code less readable.

As someone that just began learning Perl, I thought that after the following changes, at least the whole code in `while` would no longer be underlined by B::Lint, that was the case for the `while` code itself, but not for `my @num = $line =~ /(\d+)/g;`, now reporting: "*Implicit match on $_*".

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @numbers;

open(my $fh, "<", "phonenumbers.txt");
while(my $line = <$fh>) {
    my @num = $line =~ /(\d+)/g;
    push @numbers, join('',@num);
}
foreach(@numbers) {
    print("$_\n");
}
```

How is `$_` being implicitly used on `my @num = $line =~ /(\d+)/g;`? Is there a way I could avoid being warned by the linter of that implicit match by writing it differently?

Comment: `$_` is not used anywhere in that first loop.

Comment: @ikegami could this be a bug in the linter then?

Comment: If versions are relevant, I'm using Perl 5.24.1 and using the B::Lint on Atom.

Comment: Are you certain that is exactly the code you are running?  I have the feeling many more people use Perl::Critic than B::Lint, but I still have trouble imagining it would have a bug such as you describe

Comment: Most of the warnings you get are related to `implicit-read` or `dollar-underscore` options, but I don't see anything about or with that regex.  How exactly are you using `B::Lint`?  Any plugins?

Comment: @zdim Thanks, I think that could be helpful! Here is a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/gLFlvUQ.jpg) of the window.

Comment: I enabled `all` warnings and get nothing from your second script (when `foreach` and `print` are written with lexicals).

Comment: Fix the next two warnings and try again -- maybe it's getting confused somehow?  There's nothing to report on that regex.

Comment: @zdim This is indeed strange, I fixed the other two, [but the warning still remains](http://i.imgur.com/DwzFq0E.jpg). Also tried to close and re-open Atom.

Comment: There are plugins for lint, and I have no idea how Atom configures it.  The only thing I can think of is that something requires `m/` in that regex (but that would contradict `perlop` I think).

Comment: @zdim Yes, I'm using [this one](https://atom.io/packages/linter-perl), since it seems to be a bug I'll probably try another linter when developing then. Doesn't `m/` only affect `^` and `$`?

Comment: I mean `$var =~ m/.../;` (not the modifier `/m` at the end).  It shouldn't matter but I don't see what else could possibly.

Comment: I get it to happen with perl5.22.1 or perl 5.24.1 and `-MO=Lint,all`

Comment: it seems to be anytime =~ is used with a simple lexical on the left

Comment: @ysth  Yes, I am getting the same with 5.27.2, and with `-MO=Lint,implicit-read` ... but not when I declare `our $line;` at the top instead of the `my $line` in `while`. Nor with `while ($line =~ /.../) { push @num, $1; }...`

Comment: @zdim are you sure about the last?  or do you mean where it is not a lexical?  I get the bug for any lexical, regardless of context.

Comment: @ysth  I tested again with what I think I tried last night, but it does fail (warn) with: `while (my $line = <$fh>) { my @num; while ($line =~ /(\d+)/g) { push @num, $1 }; ... }`, as `perl -MO=Lint,all script.pl`. It gives the same warning even with a mere `$line =~ /(\d+)/;` statement. (I'll check later what exactly I did on the other box).  This is on 5.27.2. There were no warnings on 5.18.1 right now, for instance.

Comment: @ysth  You are right: This program: `my $v = 'hi';  $v =~ m/./;`
  triggers the warning `Implicit match on $_`, with or w/o warnings and strict and with `my $v = ''` as well. Same for `s/`.

Comment: Do you think this is worth reporting to the devs or not? Also, it probably should be another question, but is there a way to disable `implicit-read` or `dollar-underscore` options in the linter? So it could check only other important syntaxes.